# Spring Test Dont have access on TestEntityManager

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, hsqldb, spring-test, in-memory-database

I'm trying execute some test with @DataJpaTest but I cant save my object to create my assertions.

[Doc for TestEntityManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/TestEntityManager.html)

When I try save my entity, I have the following result on log:

```
15/02/2018 14:58:40.565 WARN  [main] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: -5501, SQLState: 42501
15/02/2018 14:58:40.565 ERROR [main] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: user lacks privilege or object not found: MY_VIEW in statement [select validviewl0_.cpf as cpf1_0_0_, validacaol0_.rating as rating7_0_0_ from dbo.my_view validviewl0_ where validviewl0_.cpf=?]
```

This is my annotations on test class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.ANY, connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.HSQL)
public class MyRepositoryTest {
  @Autowired
  private TestEntityManager testEntityManager

  @Autowired
  private MyRepository myRepository;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    Assert.assertTrue(testEntityManager.getEntityManager().isOpen());
    testEntityManager.persist(MyEntity.builder()
      .cpf("11122233344").build());
    testEntityManager.flush();
  }

  @After
  public void after() {
    testEntityManager.clear();
  }
}
```

The BIG problem is that I dont know how to granw this access and it is  about this message: **user lacks privilege or object not found: MY_VIEW**

Obs.: The real database (not in-memory and not on this test) is MS SQL Server.

Comment: are the database tables in the test database created automatically? could you try setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` in the test properties

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of user permissions but tables are not created in your in-memory database so you need to add `generate-ddl` to your properties.

Also try annotating test with:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.ANY)
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest
```

Add H2 or HSQL database for testing (or equivalent for Maven):

```
testCompile 'com.h2database:h2'
```

Application.yml properties example:

```
spring: 
  jpa:
    database: default
    generate-ddl: true
    properties: 
      hibernate: 
        show_sql: true 
        use_sql_comments: true
        format_sql: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:your_test_db;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    username: sa
    password: 
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
```

If you mark your test with `@Transactional`, database will be roll backed after test so you wouldn't need to use `@After` to clear it. More info at [Should my tests be @Transactional?](https://www.marcobehler.com/2014/06/25/should-my-tests-be-transactional/)

If this does not work, try simple `EntityManager` instead of `TestEntityManager`.